# My mathematica is broken, can someone help? (error "Kernet is not responding to Dynamic Evaluation")

Tags: dynamic, warning-messages, abort

I have been doing some intensity plots on mathematica and it was working fine. It stopped responding when I tried to run 'Animate' command to try to see a simulation of the same intensity plots that I had been working on. I terminated the application, but after that everytime I try to use it, it shows error that the kernel is not responding (see the attached picture). I deleted the error causing code, uninstalled and reinstalled mathematica, but it perisists. The error pops up even if I try to do a simple operation like 2+3 in a new notebook.
Can someone please help me fix it?
Thanks

[image: The Error]

Comment: Contact Wolfram Support. They are better positioned to troubleshoot something like this.

Comment: I have the same problem, This message appear every time even if I try to open help or do any thing and I tried to uninstall and install Mathematica again and this message still appear, Can anyone help me